# Receiving DTMF in Android

Tags: android, dtmf

Wanted to know if there is a way to decode the DTMF signals (sent from other phones) into numbers so that the number can be manipulated as required?

**For eg:** If I am pressing 1234 from phone A during a call I should be able to get that 1234 number on the Android phone B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this is [not supported](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1428) yet.

You can't tap into the voice call sound stream, so there is no way you can detect DTMF tones by yourself even if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible by using this project.

here is the link

https://code.google.com/p/dtmf-decoder/source/checkout